# How does $ appear at end?

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to understand ***pos***,***endpos*** and ***slice*** which using **`RegexObject`** in Python.

My Code is as following:

```
>>> import re
>>> pat=re.compile(r'^abcd')

# Starting search from index 2.
>>> print(pat.match('..abcd',2))   
None

# Slicing gives a new string "abcd" hence a match for ^ is found.
>>> pat.match('..abcd'[2:]) 
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd'>

>>> pat=re.compile(r'abcd$')

# How does $ appear at end ?
>>> pat.match('abcd..',0,4)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd'> 

# Slicing gives a new string "abcd" hence a match for ^ is found.    
>>> pat.match('abcd..'[:4])
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='abcd'>
```

My question: As string `abcd..` is not sliced in `>>> pat.match('abcd..',0,4)`

**How does `$` appear at endpos ?**

Comment: Huh. That's especially weird if you compare it to `^`, which is explicitly documented *not* to behave this way.

Comment: The docs seem to indirectly imply that `$` matches at `endpos`, but it's easy to miss if you're not reading carefully, and no rationale is provided. I suspect this is a mistake they left in for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

The `match` method [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.match):

> The optional *pos* and *endpos* parameters have the same meaning as for the `search()` method.

refer to the [`search` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search), which says

> The optional parameter *endpos* limits how far the string will be searched; it will be as if the string is *endpos* characters long, so only the characters from *pos* to `endpos - 1` will be searched for a match. If *endpos* is less than *pos*, no match will be found; **otherwise, if *rx* is a compiled regular expression object, `rx.search(string, 0, 50)` is equivalent to `rx.search(string[:50], 0)`**.

Providing an `endpos` of 4 is equivalent to slicing the string to a length of 4, so `endpos` is considered the new end of the string, and `$` matches there. This is a bizarre contrast to the interaction of `pos` and `^`, which explicitly does not work that way:

> the `'^'` pattern character matches at the real beginning of the string and at positions just after a newline, but not necessarily at the index where the search is to start.